# What's structured data is needed to show rich snippets for an ecommerce website?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, structured-data

I have ecommerce website (we sell welding equipment) with over 5k product pages (without reviews), 1k categories and many info-pages... but in main template integrated only Microdata for product pages with value - `itemprop="name"` .

I want use reach snippets for other pages, whats structured data best for my site - JSON-LD, Microdata or RDFa (or markup with schema.org)?
What structured data is best for the category page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have [Rich Snippets](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/) in Google Search, you have to use the vocabulary Schema.org with a syntax that Google supports.

Currently, Google [supports](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies#technical_guidelines) JSON-LD, Microdata and RDFa.

On Google’s ["About schema.org" page](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org), they still say that for JSON-LD only the Event Rich Snippet is supported, but this is most likely not true (anymore), as the documentation for their other Rich Snippets list JSON-LD, too. Google even recommends JSON-LD for the features it supports, and Microdata/RDFa for the ones not supported by JSON-LD; but I wouldn’t care too much about this.

Use whichever syntax works best for you. The only feature which currently seems to be exclusive to JSON-LD is that Google supports it also if it’s [dynamically injected](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/78164/17633).