# Getting this in Google SDTT Tool: "The URL could not be rendered. Some markup may be missing."

Tags: seo, javascript, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

Structured Data Testing Tool giving error in testing via fetch url but working fine when pasting the code.

I have some JS code which fetches some content and dynamically inject in the HTML. So I am thinking that's the reason of error. However I have pasted the generated code and its working fine there.

So is it that the SDTT cannot able to fetch the dynamic content via JS and gives error?

Is it a problem? because most of the website inject dynamically fetched HTML in DOM.

Does it affect the page ranking in any way? How to get rid of this error?

I have created sample URLs:

This is giving error:
http://54.83.93.238/sdk/with_error.html

This is not giving error:
http://54.83.93.238/sdk/without_error.html

Comment: [Google SDTT does not fetch structured data by URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/120706/17633)

Answer (score 1):

As i can see, testing tool has no problem with markup at its own, but with javascript. According to community's experience it makes no problem, specially for SEO. It is rather a quirk of SDTT on rendering of js. An experienced user having my full trust means [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/9178087):

> The SDTT is not very good at rendering pages. I suspect it thinks it
>   is trying to deal with your JS and failing.